# Can you pull current or past dividends data with pandas using yahoo finance api?

Tags: python, pandas, yahoo-finance, yahoo-api, pandas-datareader

I'm new to using the Yahoo finance API for pulling stock data. I watched a tutorial on youtube on how to get the OHLC data, but they never went over getting dividends. Can you pull dividends data from the Yahoo API using pandas/python?

Comment: Yes, you can. You just need to scrape the corresponding webpage on finance yahoo! To be a little more precise, more than `pandas`, you need `requests` and `BeautifulSoup`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you what you want, and a whole lot more too!

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_base = "https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t="
tckr = ['SBUX','MSFT','AAPL']
url_list = [url_base + s for s in tckr]

with open('C:\\path_where_you_want_to_download_data\\SO.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)

    for url in url_list:
        try:
            fpage = requests.get(url)
            fsoup = BeautifulSoup(fpage.content, 'html.parser')

            # write header row
            writer.writerow(map(lambda e : e.text, fsoup.find_all('td', {'class':'snapshot-td2-cp'})))

            # write body row
            writer.writerow(map(lambda e : e.text, fsoup.find_all('td', {'class':'snapshot-td2'})))            
        except HTTPError:
            print("{} - not found".format(url))
```